# ActiveRecords joins always running a SELECT COUNT(*) statement before execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the follow models:

```
class Batch < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :deliverer, optional: true
  has_many :stops, dependent: :destroy
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :stop, optional: true
end

class Stop < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :batch
  has_many :tasks
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks
end
```

I am doing a join query to get all distinct jobs:

```
batch.stops.joins(tasks: :job).select('distinct on (jobs.id) jobs.*')
```

But somehow the query always runs a `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement before running the actual sql statement:

```
   (5.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "stops" INNER JOIN "tasks" ON "tasks"."stop_id" = "stops"."id" INNER JOIN "jobs" ON "jobs"."id" = "tasks"."job_id" WHERE "stops"."batch_id" = $1  [["batch_id", 1]]
  Stop Load (3.0ms)  SELECT distinct on (jobs.id) jobs.* FROM "stops" INNER JOIN "tasks" ON "tasks"."stop_id" = "stops"."id" INNER JOIN "jobs" ON "jobs"."id" = "tasks"."job_id" WHERE "stops"."batch_id" = $1  [["batch_id", 1]]
```

Would like to know if this is intended behaviour or is this an unnecessary statement that can be prevented.

Comment: lets try solution given below and let me know for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
distinct_jobs_ids =  batch.stops.joins(tasks: :job).distinct.pluck(:'jobs.id')

distinct_jobs = Job.where(id: distinct_jobs_ids)
```

Another way to do this: -

```
distinct_jobs = distinct_jobs_ids =  batch.stops.joins(tasks: :job).select('distinct jobs')
```

Comment: hey gabbar, thanks for the answer. This query gives distinct job ids but I would like to have the whole job record. Would be great if you could explain why the `COUNT` statement disappears with your query.

Comment: @PehQinCheng  I think due to `jobs.*` in your select block it fires `COUNT` query . by the way you can get whole jobs by using `where` query as i modified answer. please check  modified answer.

Comment: @PehQinCheng feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you or let me know for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
batch.stops.joins(tasks: :job).distinct.select(jobs.id)
```

and

```
batch.stops.joins(tasks: :job).distinct.collect(jobs.id)
```

Comment: collect will fire internally loop and it will iterate over each record. so far as i think this is not feasible for large number of records.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

```
class Batch < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :deliverer, optional: true
  has_many :stops, dependent: :destroy
  # insert the following
  has_many :jobs, through: :stops
end

class Stop < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :batch
  has_many :tasks
  # insert the following
  has_many :jobs, through: :tasks, source: :job
end
```

### Usage

```
batch.jobs.distinct
```